# Finding rows which aren't in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
symbol,    name
abc        Jumping Jack
xyz        Singing Sue
rth        Fat Frog
```

I then have another dataframe with the same structure (symbol + name). I need to output all the symbols which are in the first dataframe but not the second.

The name column is allowed to differ. For example I could have `symbol = xyz` in both dataframes but with different names. That is fine. I am simply trying to get the `symbols` which do not appear in both dataframes.

I am sure this can be done using pandas merge and then outputting the rows that didn't merge, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isin` and negate the condition using `~`:

```
df[~df['symbol'].isin(df1['symbol'])]
```

This will return rows where 'symbol' is present in your first df and not in the other df